# Generalization of Fermats Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory

Is the following generalization of Fermats Last Theorem true?

Let $r≥2$ be a natural number. The equation
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{r}a_k^n=a^n
$$
Has a solution in integers $(a_1,...,a_n,a)\in\mathbb{N}^{n+1}$ if and only if $n≤r$.

I conjectured this after playing around with sum powers, but I don't know if this has already been considered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has been considered, but $27^5+84^5+110^5+133^5 = 144^5$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler conjectured the same thing, it turned out to be false. One of the big names in this is Noam Elkies, He may or may not be the one who found the very first counterexample, but he has furthered the study. Let me find some links. Of, should be in Guy, unsolved Problems in Number Theory.